# How can I clasify files based on their extension in Python?

Tags: python, file, shutil

I want to move files into folders based on their extensions and categorize them.
I've tried shutil.move() to categorize it. But it gives an error like this:

> shutil.Error: Cannot move a directory 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\deneme' into itself 'None'.

How can i fix the problem?

My code:

```
import os
from os import path
import pathlib
import shutil


path_ = input("Directory: ")
file_list = os.listdir(path_)  
os.chdir(path_)
current_directory = os.getcwd()

e = []
a = 0

for i in file_list:
    ext = os.path.splitext(i)[1][1:] 
    e.append(ext)  
    # print("Ext:", ext)

for j in range(len(e)):
    if e[j] == ",":
        j = j + 1
        continue
    os.mkdir(str(j)) 
    os.rename(str(j), e[j])  
    new_folder = e[j]

    for f in os.listdir(current_directory):
        new_directory = os.chdir(new_folder)  
        if f == ",":
            f +=1
            continue
        shutil.move(os.path.join(current_directory), str(new_directory))
        #print("it is moved")
    print(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(str(e[j]))))
```

Comment: Note that ``os.chdir`` returns ``None``, not the new directory. ``str(new_directory)`` will just be ``"None"``.

Comment: Please be aware that there are many redundancies in your code. For example, there is no point in ``os.mkdir`` only to ``os.rename`` immediately – create the folder with the desired name directly. There is also no point in using ``os.path.join`` on a single argument. Various uses of ``str`` are either redundant or hide errors (e.g. turning the absent ``new_directory`` into a valid but nonsensical value).

Answer (score 0):

Try `os.path.splitext()[1]` (it returns a list. The 0th element is the filename and the 1st is the extension) if you want to find the file extension

Comment: They already do that: ``ext = os.path.splitext(i)[1][1:]``